# HTML5 Audio: Native Controls not showing up on Android (Ionic Capacitor)

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-audio, capacitor

I'm using HTML5 Audio in my Capacitor App to play music. On iOS, the native Audio controls are showing up, like you see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAYxu.png).
Sadly, it doesn't show up on Android. Surprisingly, it shows up if I open my Ionic/Capacitor App in the browser and press play. See the Web-App: https://audio-player-sigma.vercel.app

This is my Code:

```
const player = new Audio();

player.src = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3';

player.onplay = () => {
  if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
      title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      artist: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      album: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      artwork: [
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96', sizes: '96x96', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
      ]
    });
    console.log('init mediaSession metadata');
  } else {
    console.log('mediaSession not available');
  }
};
```

So it works in the system browser, but not in .apk built by capacitor. On the iOS App aren't any problems. Everything works fine.
Github repository: https://github.com/mariusbolik/capacitor-audio-player

Any ideas how to get it working on the android capacitor project?
Thanks!

Comment: Github sends to a 404 not found

Comment: @mahen23 sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Can you please check if on android you can actually access navigator and its properties / methods ? Test on your phone, it might be that the way iOS and Android interacts with navigator() is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

From https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/struggling-with-music-controls/208360/2

`Sadly, the native audio control isn’t displayed on android. So you might use the media controls plugin for this platform.`

You will need to make use of this:
https://github.com/ingageco/capacitor-music-controls-plugin-v3

For Android.